# "New comment" link vanishes after submitting my own comment

Tags: bug, comments

Scenario:

1. I'm editing a comment.
2. “Add/show 1 other comment” appears, because someone posted another comment.
3. I'm submitting my comment, without clicking that link. Link disappears and I need to refresh entire page to actually see a comment, that was placed when I was typing my own.

Is this a bug or by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your comment without clicking this link (but by clicking <kbd>enter</kbd>), the link actually disappears, and the comment is *automatically* loaded. And as your comment appears to be after *that* comment, it loads after *that* comment.

I don't see anything confusing there.